# Is the guy who types up the credits in movies in the credits?

Tags: credits

Who types the credit in a movie really? Is he in the credits?

Comment: For particularly creative ones they even get _prominent_ credit; the biggest example that springs to my mind is the James Bond movies. IIRC the DVD set has not just one but two features on Maurice Binder who did the title sequences for just about half of the original series (pre-reboot and excluding the non-Broccoli 1967 Casino Royale).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, producers hire specialists or a company in producing credits and give them a list of cast and crew to be included in the credit roll.

And then they get their names in the credits. Generally, it's up to producers to show their names in the end credits and under which section. They can be listed under a custom section, other credits, acknowledgement etc.

Sources: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2cl6dz/i_wonder_if_the_guy_who_writes_out_the_credits/) and [Answers](http://www.answers.com/Q/Who_writes_the_credits_in_films?#slide=4)

---

<sub>I am currently looking for under which section they are credited. I will update it as soon as I find it.</sub>

Comment: These days, it seems like Scarlet Letters does the end titles for the majority of US productions. You'll usually see their credit as a single line item directly before the music credits.